# calculate no of records in selected time period using java

Tags: java

i hav below time records Stored  in a array.

```
8.10.22 AM
8.20.35 AM
8.56.46 AM
8.44.39 AM
```

So i want how many records in **8.00 AM** to **9.00 AM** time period. how can i do that using java? Here is my code...

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("c:/sample.csv")
                      while (reader.ready()) {
                 String line = reader.readLine();
                 String[] values = line.split(",");
                 String ti=values[5];
    DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    Date date = dateformat.parse(ti);  
             }
```

Comment: What format do you have them in? Something like a Joda Time "LocalTime" object would be ideal...

Comment: DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [before](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29) and [after](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) Date API methods to test if a `Date` is within a certain time range. If it is, increment a counter.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and count the number of matches.

Answer (score 0):

Are they ordered by time?  If not I would use a structure where they can be ordered, if possible.  Once you find a time that exceeds the window you are searching on, you could halt your search.  Depending on the size of the structure, this could save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through the array might not be the best way. If the dates are ordered, you might want to do a binary search to get the position of the first date before the start and after the end and calculate the number of dates in between them.